# Self Study Probability Question

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

I'm given:

$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(B) = p  
$$

and we have to prove or disproof that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq p^2  
$$

I have a strange solution that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: What about if $A=B$ ?

Comment: then $A \cap B = A \Rightarrow P(A \cap B) = P(A) = p$ and $p > p^2\  \forall p \in [0,1]$

Comment: @user2550228 Well, actually $\forall p\in(0,1)$. But yeah, for those values of $p$, the inequality you are trying to prove will clearly not hold.

Comment: upsala, yes of course. thx mate.

Comment: What is the strange solution that doesn't make any sense to you?